# Build c++ program for windows

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

I have troubles running an executable compiled from a c++ source with visual studio 2015 on a recently installed windows(without installed visual) studio .

When I run it i receive this error:
-the procedure entry point terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library -path-\VCRUNTIME140.dll (the dll and the executable are in the same directory)

Comment: I believe this is a service pack issue - make sure Visual Studio is up-to-date and that you have the very latest runtimes https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: On my os works. It doesn't work on windows without visual studio 2015.

Comment: Yes, but the version of VC++ that you compile with makes a difference. The end user has to have the latest redistributable package installed (see my above link) and you have to have the latest service packs installed for VS.

Comment: terminate() is exported by ucrtbase.dll, not vcruntime140.dll.  What kind of sledgehammer you used on the linker is hard to guess.

Comment: ok. Then how could I compile a win32 project to run on a new installed windows 8.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
in the directory with the executable were required:

```
msvcp140d.dll
vcruntime140d.dll
ucrtbased.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

As tom mentioned, you seem to have a problem with redistributable package, here's how you can fix it:

- Right click on your project in solution explorer
- Go to properties
- Under "Configuration Properties", select "General"
- Look for "Use of MFC" and set it to "Use MFC in a static library"
- Rebuild code

*It's recommended to do that for all your configurations (on the top-left corner, select "Configuration" as "All configurations"
[image]

Comment: I did that but the problem persists

Comment: Why using MFC? If you want to link the CRT statically, go to C/C++ -> Code Generation -> change to value of 'Runtime Library' from 'Multithreaded (Debug) DLL' to 'Multithreaded (Debug)'